# REST API Call via Python requests does not work on VPN

Tags: python, rest, python-requests

I am calling a REST API to Informatica from POSTMAN and Python (requests library) and find the behavior quite funny.
When I am on VPN I can only make a successful call from POSTMAN, however if I switch VPN off both Python and POSTMAN calls work perfectly.

Python script generated automatically by POSTMAN.

Error:

```
ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='use4-mdm.dm-us.informaticacloud.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /rdm-service/external/v2/export (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002393AB297C0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))
```

Any ideas what the reason might be?

**UPD**
To make my question more clear:

1. This is a corporate VPN on work laptop
2. My system does not have *_PROXY variables
3. No default proxy in requests library

   ```
    import requests
    session = requests.Session()
    session.proxies
    >>> {}
   ```
4. http.client library - same result
5. Settings in POSTMAN are in screenshot below

[image]

Comment: perhaps the server has blacklisted this particular vpn?

Comment: Most probably, you have to use a proxy server. You can check if a proxy is configured in Postman or at your OS level. You can then set the environment variable "HTTPS_PROXY" accordingly, and/or use the `proxies` parameter to requests. I can elaborate in an answer if you find your proxy settings.

Comment: @SuperStew this is a corporate VPN, besides POSTMAN calls are successful.

Comment: @Guillaume - I added additional info in the question, are these the proxy settings you had in mind?

Answer (score -1):

you may want to have a look at the "proxies" parameter of python requests :)